# How to extract vowels from a Java String variable?

Tags: java, string

I have a variable: `String term = "Torx"`

I want to remove only the vowels from my String.

So the output would is:  `"Trx"`.

How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use String replace:

```
    String Str = "torx";

    Str = Str.replace("a","");
    System.out.println(Str);        
    Str = Str.replace("e","");
    System.out.println(Str);
    Str = Str.replace("i","");
    System.out.println(Str);
    Str = Str.replace("o","");
    System.out.println(Str);
    Str = Str.replace("u","");
    System.out.println(Str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either do what David Martin did and replace all vowels with nothing, or in other words romove them:

```
String term = "Torx";

//Replacing 'a's
term = term.replaceAll("a", "").replaceAll("A", "");
//Replacing 'e's
term = term.replaceAll("e", "").repalceAll("E", "");
//Replacing 'i's
term = term.replaceAll("i", "").replaceAll("I", "");
//Replacing 'o's
term = term.replaceAll("o", "").replaceAll("O", "");
//Replacing 'u's
term = term.replaceAll("u", "").replaceAll("U", "");

System.out.println(term); //Without vowels
```

or you can search through all letters and save only the consonants:

```
String consonantTerm = "";

char[] letters = term.toCharArray();
for (char letter : letters) {
    if (letter != 'a' && letter != 'A' &&
        letter != 'e' && letter != 'E' &&
        letter != 'i' && letter != 'I' &&
        letter != 'o' && letter != 'O" &&
        letter != 'u' && letter != 'u') {
         consonantTerm += letter;
     }
}

System.out.println(consonantTerm) //Without vowels
```

> If you want the new String to be in the same variable. just add `term = consonantTerm;` after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `<string>.charAt(index)` Method with a for-loop and simply check the whole string like this. If the character is a consonant just concat it onto a result string.